# Search from whole website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have created website for E-learning portal and which consist of functionality like keyword Search from whole website (it can be anything from any table or any sentence from the whole website).

I am using asp.net Entity framework for the same.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5981/Internal-Site-Search-Engine

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i want to implement Search Functionality from Whole website.
Where user can user any keyword from website.